# Abstract parent class needs class variable of child class

Tags: mongodb, inheritance, groovy, abstract-class

I'm new to Groovy and attempting to make the jump from Python.  Unfortunately, I don't know Java well at all.   I'm working on a program that will use MongoDB for the backend, and wrote an abstract Domain class to handle the details of accessing the database.  Document content is generated dynamically from the instance's properties.

```
import Database.Server

abstract class Domain {

    ObjectId _id
    String comment
    Date created
    Date updated
    Boolean dirty=false

    static findOne(Map query=[:]) {
        newInstance( collection().findOne(query as BasicDBObject) )
    }

    static find(Map query=[:]) {
        def cursor = collection().find( query as BasicDBObject )
        cursor.collect { doc -> newInstance(doc) }
    }

    static collection() {
        //todo catch error if db hasn't been selected yet.
        def db = Server.getDB()
        return db.getCollection(this.collectionName)
    }

    static count() {
        return collection().getCount()
    }

    def fields() {
        // get all properties of the object and remove the ones we don't want to have in the collection
        Map fieldMap = properties
        ['class', 'collectionName', 'dirty'].each { fieldMap.remove(it) }
        return fieldMap
    }

    void insert() {
        //todo incorporate audit trail
        this.created = new Date()
        this.updated = new Date()
        collection().insert( fields() as BasicDBObject )
        this.dirty = false
    }

    void save() {
        // todo incorporate audit trail
        this.updated = new Date()
        collection().save( fields() as BasicDBObject )
        this.dirty = false
    }

    String toString() {
        return "${collectionName}: " + fields().collect { "\n\t$it" }
    }
}
```

So, I thought I'd be able to generate a simple collection by subclassing the abstract class and defining the name of the collection like so:

```
class Test extends Domain { 
    static String collectionName = 'test'
}
```

but, this doesn't work.   The methods defined in Domain can't see the collectionName variable defined in Test.  How can I get Domain.collection() to use a variable defined in a subclass?  This worked in Python, everything gets dumped into the instance's **dict**.

Bonus points if you can tell me how to override the property setting operator so that setting a parameter will automatically set dirty=true.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy and Java don't have any sort of inheritance of static class members.  When you say `this.collectionName` in a groovy class called `Domain`, you are referencing `Domain.collectionName`, even if you're calling the method through a subclass like `Test.collection()`.

Even so, you can achieve a similar effect with a bit of meta-programming magic.  You can add the static methods at runtime, resolving the static properties through the correct class.  Unfortunately, it's not as simple as the python equivalent.  Here's a small example:

```
class DomainHelper {
    static collection(collectionName) {
        def db = Server.getDB()
        return db.getCollection(collectionName)
    }
    static apply(domainClass) {
        domainClass.metaClass.'static'.collection = this.&collection.curry(domainClass.collectionName)
    }
}
class Test {
    static collectionName = "test"
}
DomainHelper.apply(Test)
Test.collection()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   Is there anyway to accomplish this using categories or the @Category/@Mixin pair?  

Also, where would I put `DomainHelper.apply(Test)` ?  If I put it in the file where the new Domain is defined, wouldn't it be wrapped up in a script class and not actually executed?

Comment: My initial thought was to use a mixin, but I couldn't find a way to access the class of the target class from within the mixin class.  The apply method could be called in a static initialization block in Test (e.g. `class Test { static { DomainHelper.apply(this) } ... }`).